# My loop in `R` is not working but cannot identity where I am doing wrong

Tags: r, for-loop, debugging, while-loop, counter

Following my code and `while` loop seem to not working but could not figure where is the error.

```
fc=0
tc=1

myseq = seq(fc, tc, by=0.001)


while(fc<0.8){
  for(i in 1:length(myseq)){
   
#counter1 
  if(tc-fc>0.2){
    fc=fc
  } else if (tc-fc<=0.2){
   fc=fc+0.1
  }

  #couter2
  if(tc-fc>0.2){
    tc=tc-0.1
  } else if (tc-fc<=0.2) {
    tc=1
  }
  
  print(i+1) #This part of code is too long to put here
  print(fc)
  print(tc)
  myseq = seq(fc, tc, by=0.001)
 }
}
```

Error: I want my loop to stop when `fc==0.8` but it does not to stop at `fc==0.8`. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding 8 times 0.1 to 0 does not result in 0.8 due to machine inaccuracy, it's something like 0.79999.... Could you try do avoid the fractional numbers?

Comment: @PatrickRoocks Many thanks. Interesting to know how it calculates. Very helpful. Appreciated.

Comment: @PatrickRoocks: Folllowing evaluates to 0.8 in ```R```: ```.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1=0.8```. Have I understood your comments correctly?

Comment: No it doesn't. You don't see all digits by default. Try `options(digits=20); 0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1` I get `0.79999999999999993339`

Comment: Thanks, very helpful though still trying to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with the lower bound in function `seq`:

```
> seq(fc, tc, by=0.001)
Error in seq.default(fc, tc, by = 0.001) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
> fc
[1] 1.1
> tc
[1] 1
> seq(tc, fc, by=0.001)
  [1] 1.000 1.001 1.002 1.003 1.004 1.005 1.006 1.007 1.008 1.009 1.010 1.011 1.012 1.013 1.014 1.015 1.016 1.017 1.018 1.019 1.020 1.021 1.022 1.023 1.024 1.025 1.026 1.027
 [29] 1.028 1.029 1.030 1.031 1.032 1.033 1.034 1.035 1.036 1.037 1.038 1.039 1.040 1.041 1.042 1.043 1.044 1.045 1.046 1.047 1.048 1.049 1.050 1.051 1.052 1.053 1.054 1.055
 [57] 1.056 1.057 1.058 1.059 1.060 1.061 1.062 1.063 1.064 1.065 1.066 1.067 1.068 1.069 1.070 1.071 1.072 1.073 1.074 1.075 1.076 1.077 1.078 1.079 1.080 1.081 1.082 1.083
 [85] 1.084 1.085 1.086 1.087 1.088 1.089 1.090 1.091 1.092 1.093 1.094 1.095 1.096 1.097 1.098 1.099 1.100
```

Comment: Am I correct to think that ```while``` is not doing the job it is suppose to do? I am confused, why ```fc``` is not stopping at 0.8. Any suggestions? Any suggestions to avoid the loop will also be highly appreciated.